# Dojo datagrid Codeigniter Restful and PUT method

Tags: codeigniter, datagrid, dojo

I´m developing a web site using a **Dojo Datagrid widget**, populating the data with a **Restful service**

The restful library that I´m using is from chriskacerguis on **Codeigniter:**

**https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver**

The only framework that I´m using is **Dojo Toolkit 1.10**

I´ve got populate the Datagrid without problems using a GET request, but the problem comes when I´m trying to modify one record of the datagrid and the datagrid fires a PUT request.

I get the following from the console:

- XHR finished loading: GET "www.website/Codeigniter/Civilweb/restful/user/?id=*". dojo.js:15
- **PUT** www.website/Codeigniter/Civilweb/restful/user/1 **404 (Not Found)** dojo.js:15
- XHR finished loading: **PUT** "www.website/Codeigniter/Civilweb/restful/user/1". dojo.js:15
- _5a6: Unable to load www.website/Codeigniter/Civilweb/restful/user/1 status: 404 {message: "Unable to load www.website/Codeigniter/Civilweb/restful/user/1 status: 404", response: Object, status: 404, responseText: "", xhr: XMLHttpRequest…} dojo.js:15

I don´t know why but finally the record is modified on my "MySQL" database, but I need to refresh the page to see the changes.

This is the code of my view:

```
var dataStoreSetup1 = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({
                                target:"http://localhost/Codeigniter/Civilweb/restful/user/" ,
                                idAttribute: 'id',
                                idProperty: 'id'
                                });     

                 var layoutSetup1 = [{
                                        defaultCell: { width: 8, editable: true, type: cells._Widget, styles: 'text-align: center;'  },
                                        cells: [

                                            {name: 'Name',      field: 'name'      ,width:10},
                                            {name: 'Position',  field: 'position'  ,width:8},
                                            {name: 'User',      field: 'user'      ,width:8},
                                            {name: 'Password',  field: 'password'  ,width:8},
                                            {name: 'Role',      field: 'role'      ,width:6}
                                          ]
                                    }];

                                    var gridSetup1 = new DataGrid({
                                        id: 'gridSetup1',
                                        query: { id: "*" },
                                        store: dataStoreSetup1,//dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: dataStoreSetup1}),
                                        structure: layoutSetup1,
                                        loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
                                        noDataMessage : "No results found.",
                                        clientSort: 'false',
                                        selectionMode:'single',
                                        rowSelector: '0px',
                                        onApplyCellEdit : procOnApplyCellEdit
                                        });

                                    //append the new grid to the div  
                                    gridSetup1.placeAt("gridDivSetup1");

                                    //Call startup() to render the grid
                                    gridSetup1.update();
                                    gridSetup1.startup();

                function procOnApplyCellEdit() {

                     dataStoreSetup1.save();    

                }
```

This is my controller:

```
 function user_get() //respond with information
{

    $this->load->model('setup_model');

    if(!$this->get('id'))
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 400);  //Bad Request
    }

    $user = $this->setup_model->get_users_data();

    if($user)
    {
        $this->response->format = 'json';
        $this->response($user, 200); //200 being the HTTP response code
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 404);  //Not found
    }

}


function user_put() // update an existing user and respond with a status/errors
{       

    $this->load->model('setup_model');

    $result = $this->setup_model->put_users_data($this->put('id'),$this->put('name'),$this->put('position'),$this->put('user'),$this->put('password'),$this->put('role'));


    if($result)
    {
       $this->response($result, 200); //200 being the HTTP response code
    }

    else
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 404);  //Not found
    }
```

And finally this is my model:

```
public function get_users_data()               
  {
      $query = $this->db->get('users');
      if($query->num_rows() > 0)
      {
          return $query->result_array();
      }

  }

public function put_users_data($id,$name,$position,$user,$password,$role)
  {

    $data = array(
        'name'     =>  $name,
        'position' =>  $position,
        'user'     =>  $user,
        'password' =>  $password,
        'role'     =>  $role
    );

    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update('users',$data);

  }
```

What I´m doing wrong and Why I get this 404 error from PUT method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The dojo put request seems fine. You should probably check what is happening with $result in function user_put() of your controller. Is it async?
http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: Thanks Bobz79 the issue was in the $result, I don´t know why, but $result returned NULL. Now it works like a charm. Thanks again

Comment: Cool, glad to know it works now. I will post the comment as answer to get the points :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dojo put request seems fine. You should probably check what is happening with $result in function user_put() of your controller. Is it async?

[restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html](http://restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)